# JavaFX 2.2 turn.js does not work in WebView?

Tags: javascript, webview, javafx-2, javafx

I would like to use turn.js in a JavaFX application using a WebView. For this I created a WebView where the content is set as followed:

```
@FXML
private WebView webView;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    final WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();

    try {
        engine.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        engine.load(readHtml());

        engine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> ov, Worker.State oldState, Worker.State newState) {
                if (State.SUCCEEDED == newState) {
                    startTurnJS(engine);
                }
            }

        });
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       // exception handling omitted
    }
}

private String readHtml() throws Exception {
    String result = getClass().getResource("turnjscontainer.html").toExternalForm();

    return result;
}
```

The turnjscontainer.html file contains

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.turnjs.com/lib/turn.min.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            background:#ccc;
        }
        #magazine{
            width:700px;
            height:450px;
        }
        #magazine .turn-page{
            background-color:#ddd;
            background-size:100% 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="magazine">
        <div style="background-image:url(http://www.hsv.de/fileadmin/redaktion/Verein/hsv-logo-neu.jpg);"></div>
        <div style="background-image:url(http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQZlRvgmbKf7U8p0v47vVG2AjBS_IdY00kz74ZtNjWEl1EAs9eOWc15uQ);"></div>
    </div>


    <!-- <script type="text/javascript">

         $(window).ready(function() {
             $('#magazine').turn({
                 display: 'single',
                 acceleration: true,
                 gradients: !$.isTouch,
                 elevation: 50,
                 when: {
                     turned: function(e, page) {
                     }
                 }
             });
         });

         $(window).bind('keydown', function(e) {

             if (e.keyCode == 37)
                 $('#magazine').turn('previous');
             else if (e.keyCode == 39)
                 $('#magazine').turn('next');

         });

     </script>-->

</body>
</html>
```

The javascript part is commented because I execute the script from within the controller by invoking startTurnJS() after document loading has finished:

```
private void startTurnJS(final WebEngine engine) {
    engine.executeScript("$(window).ready(function() {\n"
            + "                $('#magazine').turn({\n"
            + "                    display: 'single',\n"
            + "                    acceleration: true,\n"
            + "                    gradients: !$.isTouch,\n"
            + "                    elevation: 50,\n"
            + "                    when: {\n"
            + "                        turned: function(e, page) {\n"
            + "                        }\n"
            + "                    }\n"
            + "                });\n"
            + "            });");

    engine.executeScript("$(window).bind('keydown', function(e) {\n"
            + "\n"
            + "                if (e.keyCode == 37)\n"
            + "                    $('#magazine').turn('previous');\n"
            + "                else if (e.keyCode == 39)\n"
            + "                    $('#magazine').turn('next');\n"
            + "\n"
            + "            });");
}
```

The result in the WebView is that only the first image is shown which at least indicates that the javascript has been executed. However no turn.js functionality is available.

If you uncomment the  part in the HTML file and load the page in a browser turn.js works. So I am wondering if it is possible to get turn.js work within WebView?

Comment: Can you uncomment the js code in HTML and wrap it into another function say `init()` and call this from webEngine, `engine.executeScript("init();");`.

Comment: @Uluk Biy thanks for your tip. I tried it without success. Image is shown but nothing more..

Comment: Where did you put jquery and turn js files in the project? Are they in the same package of the turnjscontainer.html? How are they imported into html? You may need to import js files through getClass().getResource().

Comment: Yes they are in the turnjscontainer.html. For some unknown reason they don't appear in the html which i posted above. After <head> I put the script tags: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.turnjs.com/lib/turn.min.js"></script>.

Comment: I tried booklet, a jquery flipbook plugin. Booklet works out of the box within WebView. It does not look as nice as turn.js but it will be sufficient. Hard to know if it is a problem with WebView or turn.js. Anyway I am about to file a bug for JavaFX because turn.js works in a browser without problems.

Comment: Yeah, WebView uses WebKit internally, so the problem maybe in incompatibility issues. The good news is the right-left keys are working to turn the page, but not so smooth as in webbrowser.